# Kenburns effect undefined error - React Native

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, native

My code:

```
              <Swiper
                controlsProps={{
                  dotsTouchable: true,
                  dotsWrapperStyle: { backgroundColor: "lightblue" },
                  dotsPos: "top",
                  DotComponent: ({ index, isActive, onPress }) => (
                    <Button onPress={onPress} style={styles.DOT}></Button>
                  ),
                }}
                loop
                timeout={3}
              >
                {prefixData.length !== 1 ? (
                  prefixData?.map((e, i) => {
                    return _renderKenburnImg(e, i)
                  })
                ) : (
                  <></>
                )}
              </Swiper>
```

And:

```
const _renderKenburnImg = (e: string, i: number) => (
    <View style={styles.IMG_CONTAINER}>
      <KenBurnsImage
        tension={6}
        friction={50}
        imageWidth={Dimensions.get("window").width}
        imageHeight={300}
        sourceUri={{
          uri: e,
        }}
      ></KenBurnsImage>
    </View>
  )
```

After go to last image, RN show error: **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'spring.systemShouldAdvance').** Please help! Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `rebound.js` file, delete or hide code relates to `deregisterSpring`.